# Does a weighted sum constraint $\sum_i^K w_if(x-a_i)=C$ imply $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Suppose that function $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and that there is a weighted sum constraint
$$\sum_{i=1}^K w_if(x-a_i)=C,$$
where $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^K$, $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^K$, and $C>0$ are fixed constants, and $\sum_{i=1}^K w_i=1$, $w_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,K$.

The question is: Does $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = +\infty$ hold?

For the $K=2$ case, suppose $a_1>a_2$, I got
$$
f(x-a_1)+f(x-a_2)\ge \frac{w_1f(x-a_1)+w_2f(x-a_2)}{\text{max}\{w_1,w_2\}}\ge C,
$$
so for any $b\in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
\int_{b-(a_{1}-a_2)}^{b+(a_1-a_2)}f(x)dx & =\int_{b-(a_1-a_2)}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{b}^{b+(a_1-a_2)}f(x)dx\\
& = \int_{b-(a_1-a_2)}^{b}\left(f(x)+f(x+(a_1-a_2))\right)dx\\
& \ge \int_{b-(a_1-a_2)}^{b}Cdx\\
& = (a_1-a_2)C,
\end{align}
which means that the integral on any interval with length $2(a_1-a_2)$ is larger than a positive constant, so
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = +\infty.$$
I guess it also holds for $K\ge3$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just integrate both sides over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It does hold. It's not necessary to avoid the integrated intervals intersecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We go to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\infty$, where
the integral is interpreted in Lebesgue sense or improper Riemann
sense (they are the same because $f\geq0$). Below, I treat every
integral as Lebesgue integral. Moreover, we adopt the usual convention
in real anlaysis that $\infty+a=\infty$ and $b\cdot\infty=\infty$
for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b>0$.

Denote $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ (Note that $I$ may take
value $\infty$). Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{K}w_{i}f(x-a_{i})dx & = & \sum_{i=1}^{K}w_{i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-a_{i})dx\\
 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{K}w_{i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx\\
 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{K}w_{i}I\\
 & = & I.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\sum_{i=1}^{K}w_{i}f(x-a_{i})=C>0$,
so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{K}w_{i}f(x-a_{i})dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Cdx=\infty$.
It follows that $I=\infty$.